# Help with a foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

In my website I am trying to display all the applicants to jobs that a user has posted, basically I want the out put to simimlar too,

> Job Title 1
>   Aplicant Name 1
>   Aplicant Name 2
>   Applicant Name 3
>
> Job Title 2
>   Applicant Name 4
>   Application Name 5

Basically I want the applications to be gathered under the jobs they applied for, however the out put I am current getting is,

> Job Title 1
>   Application Name 1
>
> Job Title 1
>   Applicant Name 2

The code I am using to do this foreach loop is as follows

```
<?php foreach($applications as $a) : ?>
        <h3><?php echo $a['jobtitle']; ?></h3>
    <li>
        <img src="/media/uploads/candidates/<?php echo preg_replace('/(.gif|.jpg|.png)/', '_thumb$1', $a['profile_image']);?>" width="90" height="60"/>
        <p><?php echo $a['name']; ?></p>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Can you post a print_r or var_dump of `$applications`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need the data structure to properly answer, but I'm assuming you need a nested foreach...

```
<? foreach($jobs as $j): ?>

# list jobs

    <? foreach($applicants as $a): ?>
        <? if ($j['jobtitle'] == $a['jobtitle']): ?>

        # list applicants

        <? endif; ?>
    <? endforeach; ?>    

<? endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you are getting that because you are only outputting

```
$a['jobtitle']
```

and

```
$a['name']
```

Where are the other names stored? Something like this is probably what you want, although that won't work if you copy/paste it as it seems that $applications[x]['name'] is not an array:

```
<?php foreach($applications as $a) : ?>
        <h3><?php echo $a['jobtitle']; ?></h3>
    <li>
        <img src="/media/uploads/candidates/<?php echo preg_replace('/(.gif|.jpg|.png)/', '_thumb$1', $a['profile_image']);?>" width="90" height="60"/>
        <?php foreach($a['name'] as $name)?>
        <p><?php echo $name; ?></p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend pulling jobtitle and applicants from the database and storing them in a multidimensional array.

```
$jobs[$jobtitle][] = $applicant_name;
```

Then looping through this array in your view.  I've omitted your image code for clarity.

```
foreach($jobs as $title=>applicants){
    echo $title;
    foreach($applicants as $name){
        echo $name;
    }
}
```